# When I run the spark sample for logistic regression, I get a perfect model. Did I screw up

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running the example code from the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#binomial-logistic-regression) for logistic regression using pyspark and the attendant training summary code:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

# Load training data
training = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("/user/tim/sample_svm/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)

# Fit the model
lrModel = lr.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients and intercept for logistic regression
print("Coefficients: " + str(lrModel.coefficients))
print("Intercept: " + str(lrModel.intercept))

# We can also use the multinomial family for binary classification
mlr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8, family="multinomial")

# Fit the model
mlrModel = mlr.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients and intercepts for logistic regression with multinomial family
print("Multinomial coefficients: " + str(mlrModel.coefficientMatrix))
print("Multinomial intercepts: " + str(mlrModel.interceptVector))

# Extract the summary from the returned LogisticRegressionModel instance trained
# in the earlier example
trainingSummary = lrModel.summary

# Obtain the objective per iteration
objectiveHistory = trainingSummary.objectiveHistory
print("objectiveHistory:")
for objective in objectiveHistory:
    print(objective)

# Obtain the receiver-operating characteristic as a dataframe and areaUnderROC.
trainingSummary.roc.show(500)
print("areaUnderROC: " + str(trainingSummary.areaUnderROC))

# Set the model threshold to maximize F-Measure
fMeasure = trainingSummary.fMeasureByThreshold
maxFMeasure = fMeasure.groupBy().max('F-Measure').select('max(F-Measure)').head()
bestThreshold = fMeasure.where(fMeasure['F-Measure'] == maxFMeasure['max(F-Measure)']) \
    .select('threshold').head()['threshold']
lr.setThreshold(bestThreshold)
```

and get:

```
areaUnderROC: 1.0
```

which I wouldn't expect. Perhaps it overfit and simply memorized the data, but I've done train and test, even randomized labels, and tweaked all the hyper parameters and they all led to the same thing:AUC=1.0. I tried the sample code for the SVC models, which uses the same dataset, and I get the same thing.

I'd normally post the code, but I literally ran the example code only changing the path to the data file.  I've searched and searched and can find no example of anyone having run this example and examined the results. What's odd is that this dataset, sample_libsvm_data.txt, is used throughout the docs yet I can find neither analysis of it nor even an explanation of what the data actually is.

As a result I've switched to using the RDD-based API of MLLIB because I can't make sense of the results of the sample code. I hope someone can tell me how I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT: 
As requested, here's the [entire datafile](https://gist.github.com/timtiptoes/88bfda6be134b2482a8fa54264698f5a).

Comment: Hard to be sure without sample code, but it could be that there is a feature (or linear combination of features) that is a perfect predictor for the labels? Perhaps even the labels column has somehow gotten included in your features?

Comment: David, makes sense. But what's crazy is that I executed the code from the docs verbatim save for the file path.

Comment: Can you post the first few lines from the data file?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using pyspark with dataframes for quite some time, and I've
   had positive experinces using dataframes over RDD, as they resemble
   the pandas dataframes. So for changing that in your approach I don't
   find it as a good solution for your problem.

The hypothesis of "simply memorized the data" is not a valid solution
   for your problem. Check it yourself, simple change the name of the
   objects and variables and see the same output.

So looking at this specific piece of code you put there you say you
   got an `AUC_ROC=1.0`. My first intuition is because your are analysing
   the summary statistcs of the training set not the test. You are most
   likely correct the model overfit on the training set. However, with a
   test set I doubt the value would get the same results. So I went and
   evaluated it myself:

```
result = lrModel.transform(training)
result.prediction
result.show()
```

List item

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(rawPredictionCol="rawPrediction")
AUC_ROC = evaluator.evaluate(result,{evaluator.metricName: "areaUnderROC"})
print('AUC ROC:' + str(AUC_ROC))
```

#### final results

AUC ROC:1.0

In other words, you are correct the model overfits... But these are the results for the train set, and it's working correctly. And indeed the AUC have 1.0 for the piece of code you provided.

Bottom line is, it is a bad example to be included in the spark documentation. Try it in other datasets with this code

So checking the API documentation, here is another example but this time you have the expected results... sadly 1.0 again... really bad choice  of examples from spark I must admit: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression